# Java 8 Collectors.groupingBy with mapped value to set collecting result to the same set

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Objects are used in example are from package `org.jsoup.nodes`

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

I need group attributes by key with resulting value `Set`.

```
Optional<Element> buttonOpt = ...;
Map<String, Set<String>> stringStringMap =
    buttonOpt.map(button -> button.attributes().asList().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Attribute::getKey, 
                  mapping(attribute -> attribute.getValue(), toSet()))))
            .orElse(new HashMap<>());
```

It seems collected correctly, but value all the time is single string (because of library implementation) that contains different values split by space. Trying to improve solution:

```
Map<String, Set<HashSet<String>>> stringSetMap = buttonOpt.map(
        button -> button.attributes()
            .asList()
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Attribute::getKey, 
                        mapping(attribute -> 
                          new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(attribute.getValue()
                                                                .split(" "))),
                   toSet()))))
  .orElse(new HashMap<>());
```

In result i've got different structure `Map<String, Set<HashSet<String>>>` but i need `Map<String, Set<String>>`

I've checked some collectors but have not managed my issue.

### Question is:

How to merge all sets that related to the same attribute key?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can split your attributes with `flatMap` and create new entries to group:

```
Optional<Element> buttonOpt = ...
Map<String, Set<String>> stringStringMap =
        buttonOpt.map(button -> 
            button.attributes()
                  .asList()
                  .stream()
                  .flatMap(at -> Arrays.stream(at.getValue().split(" "))
                                       .map(v -> new SimpleEntry<>(at.getKey(),v)))
                  .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                      mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toSet()))))
                .orElse(new HashMap<>());
```

Comment: What's `at.getKey`, might be a typo there with a missing `()`

Comment: I suggest using `orElse(Collections.emptyMap())` instead, as there is no need to instantiate a new `HashMap` (and the `groupingBy` collector without a map supplier doesn’t guaranty to produce a `HashMap`, so the caller should not assume it).

Answer (score 15):

Here's a Java9 way of doing it,

```
Map<String, Set<String>> stringSetMap = buttonOpt
    .map(button -> button.attributes().asList().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Attribute::getKey, Collectors.flatMapping(
            attribute -> Arrays.stream(attribute.getValue().split(" ")), Collectors.toSet()))))
    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

Comment: Nice! I'd only suggest `orElseGet(HashMap::new)` instead of `orElse(new HashMap<>())` to make it a little bit cleaner.

Comment: `orElse(HashMap::new)` wouldn't compiler either...made an edit for the same.

Comment: @nullpointer It was supposed to be `orElseGet` instead of `orElse`. I made the proper edit.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski Well for an initialization of a HashMap I don't think `orElse` and `orElseGet` would make difference. But still, both of them should execute just fine.

Comment: @nullpointer It's just for readability. In terms of execution, the difference is most likely insignificant.

Answer (score 7):

This becomes less complicated if you use a more suitable data structure for it, namely a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap).

Multimaps are present e.g. in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), where you can do this as follows:

```
SetMultimap<String, String> stringMultimap = buttonOpt
        .map(button -> button.attributes().asList().stream()
                .collect(ImmutableSetMultimap.flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap(
                        Attribute::getKey,
                        attribute -> Arrays.stream(attribute.getValue().split(" "))
                ))
        ).orElse(ImmutableSetMultimap.of());
```

I made it immutable ([`ImmutableSetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html)), but a mutable version can also be obtained using [`Multimaps.flatteningToMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#flatteningToMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-).